# How can I verify if a linear system has a solution

Tags: integer-programming, discrete-optimization

Given $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ and a system of two-equation:
$$
\begin{cases}
\langle \vec{a}, \vec{x} \rangle = 0 \\
 \langle \vec{b}, 1-\vec{x} \rangle = 0 
\end{cases}
$$
where $\vec{x} \in \{0, 1\}^d$. Here $\langle,\rangle$ refers to inner product and $1-\vec{x}$ referrs to all 1 vector minus $\vec{x}$.

How can I verify such a system exists a solution for $\vec{x}$?

If there are solutions, how can I enumerate all of them?

Comment: This does not always have a solution. E.g. let $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b} = \mathbb{1}$. Then because $\mathbf{x}$ cannot have negative components, $\langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{x} \rangle = 0$ forces $\mathbf{x} = \mathbb{0}$. But then $\langle \mathbf{b}, \mathbb{1} - \mathbf{x} \rangle = d \neq 0$.

Comment: yes, that's why the first part of the question is about a method to verify if there exists a solution.

Comment: Then your wording is misleading: it sounded like you were assuming the system always had a solution and just wanted to verify that fact. You should rephrase it to "Is there are method to verify when the system has a solution ..."

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, just edited the title

Comment: Any linear system can be solved over the real numbers using standard methods such as Gaussian elimination (row reduction). You could simply find that solution and plug in $0$ and $1$ for all the free variables to see if any of them result in a solution of the desired type.

Answer (score 1):

For small $d$ you can of course enumerate all $x\in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^d$ and try them all in the system of equations.

More generally, to determine if a solution exists you can treat the problem as a binary integer program with a trivial objective function (minimize 0 subject to your two equations) and solve it with any MIP solver. One (time-consuming) way to enumerate all solutions is to solve the IP model, add a constraint prohibiting the solution you got (and only that solution), and repeat. To eliminate a solution $x=\hat{x}$, you add the constraint $$\sum_{i:\hat{x}_i=0} x_i + \sum_{j:\hat{x}_j=1} (1-x_j) \ge 1.$$